# plot circle segment defined by three points with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

### How can I plot the circle segment defined by three points with `ggplot2`?

I can only find the `geom_curve` function and that does define a segment by two points and the `curvature` argument.

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(2,2.5,1)
)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(col = "red") + xlim(0,4) + ylim(0,4)
p + geom_curve(aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[3], yend = y[3]))
```

[image]

With changing the `curvature` argument I can come close to what I want:

```
p + geom_curve(aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[3], yend = y[3]), curvature = -.8)
```

[image]

How can I calculate the `curvature` value given the three points (in order the segment really passes the *middle* point)?

Or even better: Are there alternative `geom_` functions out there (in `ggplot2` or an extension) that calculate segments by three points?

And the *bonus question*: Is there an alternative `geom_` that really plots *circle* segments (since the `geom_curve` is not a circle segment but some fancy curve which can be seen best when setting `curvature > 1`)?

---

Edit after comment: `ggforce::geom_bezier` doesn't seem to do the trick. I tried:

```
library(ggforce)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(2,2.5,1),
  type = "quadratic",
  point = c("end", "control", "end")
)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(col = "red") + xlim(0,4) + ylim(0,4)
p + geom_bezier(aes(x = x, y = y, group = type, linetype = type), data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe [ggforce::geom_bezier](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html#beziers) ?

Comment: @zx8754: Thx for your hint, but I can't see how `geom_bezier` should do the trick, see my edit..

Comment: Was just a big **maybe**. :)

Comment: @zx8754: thx anyway. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution. Firstly, a function to compute the circumcircle of three points:

```
circumcircle <- function(p1,p2,p3){
  x1 <- p1[1]; y1 <- p1[2]
  x2 <- p2[1]; y2 <- p2[2]
  x3 <- p3[1]; y3 <- p3[2]
  a <- det(cbind(rbind(p1,p2,p3),1))
  q1 <- c(crossprod(p1))
  q2 <- c(crossprod(p2))
  q3 <- c(crossprod(p3))
  q <- c(q1,q2,q3)
  x <- c(x1,x2,x3)
  y <- c(y1,y2,y3)
  Dx <- det(cbind(q,y,1))
  Dy <- -det(cbind(q,x,1))
  c <- det(cbind(q,x,y))
  center <- 0.5*c(Dx,Dy)/a
  r <- sqrt(c(crossprod(center-p1)))
  list(center = center, radius = r)
}

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(2,2.5,1)
)

p1 <- c(df[1,"x"], df[1,"y"])
p2 <- c(df[2,"x"], df[2,"y"])
p3 <- c(df[3,"x"], df[3,"y"])

circle <- circumcircle(p1, p2, p3)
```

Now,

```
angle <- function(p, c){
  M <- p-c
  Arg(M[1] + 1i*M[2])
}

a1 <- angle(p1, circle$center)
a2 <- angle(p2, circle$center)
a3 <- angle(p3, circle$center)
angle0 <- min(c(a1,a2,a3))
angle1 <- max(c(a1,a2,a3))

path <- function(n=10){
  theta <- seq(angle0, angle1, length.out = n)
  as.data.frame(
    sweep(circle$radius*cbind(x=cos(theta), y=sin(theta)), 2, circle$center, "+")
  )
}
```

And the plot:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
  geom_path(aes(x=x, y=y), data = path(100))
```

[image]

With an aspect ratio of 1:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
  geom_path(aes(x=x, y=y), data = path(100)) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's an option following the method shown by @Zaz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points)

Create function for calculating center and radius of circle

```
library(dplyr)

get_circle <- function(df){
  # df: three-row data frame containing columns x and y
  mat <- 
    df %>% 
      transmute(ss = x^2 + y^2, x, y, ones = 1) %>% 
      as.matrix

  center <- 
    c(x = det(mat[,c('ss', 'y', 'ones')]), y = -det(mat[,c('ss', 'x', 'ones')])
    )/(2*det(mat[,c('x', 'y', 'ones')]))

  r <- sqrt(sum((unlist(df[1, c('x', 'y')]) - center)^2))

  list(center = center, r = r)
}
```

Plot circle for given 3 points

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(2,2.5,1)
)

circle <- get_circle(df)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(col = "red") +
  with(circle,
       annotate("path",
        x = center['x'] + r*cos(seq(0,2*pi, length.out = 100)),
        y = center['y'] + r*sin(seq(0,2*pi, length.out = 100))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can we also just plot the circle *segment* (as in my question and Stéphane Laurents answer) using your approach?

Comment: huh, somehow I completely missed that part of the question. I can't think of a better method than the one Stéphane  gives. If you want to use `get_circle` instead of `circumcircle` to create the `circle` object, you should still be able to use the second half of that answer (after the first code block), since the `circle` object created should be exactly the same.